# What is the wrong with this Mysql select ,php code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I tring to run this code any result not showing.Please help me

... some code is here...

```
$result = mysql_query("select  *  from dataform where  date between '" . $d1 . "' and '" . $d2 . "'");

if (!$result) {
    echo 'No result';
}
else{
    echo $d1;
    echo $d2;
    echo "<table class=\"hovertable\">";

    echo "
<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">";

    echo "<th>File No</th>";
    echo "<th>Manufactor</th>";
    echo "<th>Address</th>";
    echo "<th>Supplier</th>";
    echo "<th>Place Site</th>";
    echo "<th>Tender Ref</th>";
    echo "<th>Award No</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\">";
        echo "<th>" . $row["fileno"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["manufacture"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["address"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["sup"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["placesite"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["tenderref"] . "</th>";
        echo "<th>" . $row["awardno"] . "</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: `if(!$result){ echo mysql_error(); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping your column `DATE` with backtick **`** because it is a MySQL Data type. Another Suggestion is avoidusing string concatenation of your query because it is prone to mysql injection. Use **[PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**.

Example of using PDO:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dataform WHERE  `date` BETWEEN ? AND ?");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $d1);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $d2);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Fetch all results in form of associative array.

?>
```

***Remember to always sanitize your inputs.***

**UPDATE 1**

You are not checking for condition in your `WHILE` loop. The way you are doing now is you are assign a value which is wrong. Try using `==`

instead of

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

}
```

change it to this

```
while ($row == mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

}
```

Comment: can you try running your query in management tool? eg mysql workbench or phpmyadmin and see if it return results.

Comment: one more thing, see my updated answer. instead of `=`, use `==` in your while loop.

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo: That's incorrect. The point is to check whether `mysql_fetch_array()` exists, and set it to `$row` at the same time. You aren't checking for equality.

Comment: @John Totet Woo, i tried to running my code in mysql workbench but the result is return.

Comment: please help me this is very important project,can you guess what is the fault?